# iFrame is not showing result if changed from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

javascript code:

```
<script>

    function searchall()
    {
        var search = document.getElementById("txtSearch");
        var frame1 = document.getElementById("frame1");

        frame1.src = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=" + search.value;
        alert(frame1.src);
    }

</script>
```

html code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" class="form-control my-txt-box" ></asp:TextBox>
    <input id="btnAll" class="my-btn" onclick="searchall()" type="button" value="Search All" />

        <iframe id="frame1" src="home.aspx">
            does not support
        </iframe>
```

my code seems to be correct but still iFrame does not show the result, its blank. I dont understand why. I even checked with **alert(frame1.src);** iframe src is setting correct but not showing result.

please help

Comment: Your HTML is missing txtSearch - is it there in your code?

Comment: yes its there please see the updated code:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It gives me an error (search.value undefined) where is the txtSearch input ?

If I put a txtSearch input it gives me the folowing error:

> Refused to display 'https://www.google.co.in/search?q=xxx' in a frame
>   because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

The header of HTTP response from google.com has:

```
x-frame-options:SAMEORIGIN
```

It disables the page rendering in an iframe. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MppZGX

**EDIT:**
The iframe hosting option for displaying search results is no longer supported by google. See: https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/4542055?hl=en  and https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/2641279?hl=en

Comment: ok, I got you, so is there any other way to achieve what I want.??

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options . This could be possible if you add a header in your main page.

Answer (score 0):

Try to refresh your iframe on function ending:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('youriframe');
iframe.src = iframe.src;
```

Also, switch var "search" ID by "btnAll". The "txtSearch" is not on your HTML.

Comment: @ArnoldParge your variable it's not right: var search = document.getElementById("txtSearch");. There is no input with ID called txtSearch, you put "btnAll". Try to set the same.